# Connecting to multiple SFTP sites using pysftp in a loop: "AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'CnOpts'"

Tags: python, loops, sftp, pysftp

There are two SFTP sites where I have the username and password. They both have the same directory within them and on the same host. I am trying to write a code in Python to loop through these sites and save the file in the folder. I have never written code pulling data from SFTP, so if I use some wrong terms please let me know.

I do not know the best way to give an example.. I will add my code that works on the first iteration, but then crashes on the second with this error:

> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'CnOpts'

I also noticed that when I run the code without the loop and just pull data from one SFTP at a time, if I try to run the code a 2nd time I get the same error. I then clear the kernels and I can run the process again.

My code that works on the first iteration and then crashes on the 2nd is below. This code will not run on your machine, but thought to add it for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import pysftp as sftp

data = {'UserName': ['User Name1', 'User Name2'],
        'Password': ['Password-1', 'Password-2']}
user_password_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

## Creating the sftp connection
raw_ftp_list = []
cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
for x, j in user_password_df.iterrows():
    cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    host = 'sampleftp.site.com'
    user = j.iloc[0]
    pswd = j.iloc[1]
    with sftp.Connection(host=host, username=user, password=pswd, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        sftp.cwd('SAMPLE/DIR/') ## selecting remote directory
        server_files = sftp.listdir()
        # ...
```

I feel that I need to add something at the end on the loop to "reset" my connection, but I do not know what that is. I tried a simple `del cnopts` to delete the variable causing the problem. That did not work. I also tried adding `sftp.close()` at the end of the iteration but that did not work either. Also, I need this code to be able to loop through infinite sftp sites because my data frame with username and password will be getting updated and more sites will be created in the future.

Any suggestions or solutions to try would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begging, `sftp` is a module. So `sftp.CnOpts()` refers to a class in the module.

But with `with ... as sftp`, you override the meaning of `sftp` identifier. So on the other iteration, the `sftp.CnOpts()` is not valid anymore, as `sftp` refers to `Connection` class and not to `sftp` module.

Rename your `sftp` variable to something else.